# UINavigationController in game development

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I've started developing my first game. Here some my thoughts about architecture:
Most examples use the project template based on single view and manage of control visibility by hand. In my game I've 6-7 views and I'd like use Interface Builder for some of them. There are some problems too:

1. If I use a single based view I'll need, for example, in "Play" button's handler to create new view with a game board and destroy previous one (the view contains that button's handler). Is it right and how can I do it?
2. If I use a navigation based view I'll use push/pop methods but I'll need to hide a navigation bar for game atmosphere and to do navigation by hand. Moreover, I couldn't find any example of use a navigation controller in games. Does anybody use it and how?

What can you advice me?

Comment: Hi! As I understand your game has a lot views.  I don't create game with UINavigationController. Why do not you want to create your game with using UIViewController?

Comment: Hi, upon single based view I mean UIView + UIViewController. I want or not it is a question. Now I consider 2 ways and choose better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you can hide navigation bar from nib file.

2) you can remove navigation animation by setting animation by   [self pushViewController:nav animated:NO];

3)if you do not want to use navigation controller , you can use view based application  and through coding you can add/remove subviews and views as per need.

Comment: Thanks! About 3rd point... Could you give an example how I can switch from button's handler of one subview to another subview?

Comment: [self.view addSubView:yourSubView.view];

Comment: if you have 5 views [self.view addSubView:view1]; if you want to add view2 then [view1 removeFromSuperView]; [self.view addSubView:view2];...

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was misunderstood. The main problem, as I see, a synchronous call the method of creating new subview from a subview and futher removing the source subview. It seems removing a subview from a button's handler located in that subview.